# wpf listview adding images into a listviewitem at runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, enums, bit-manipulation

Hi guys I am working on a project in C# WPF where I need to display a client's status in a listview
So I have the following enum that defines a Client Status

```
//Values used here for Bitwise Operations
public enum ClientStatus 
{
    NONE = 0,
    NEWCLIENT = 1, 
    MONITORED = 2, 
    IMPORTAND = 4,  
    DISATISFIED = 8, 
    DETERIORATING = 16, 
    SATISFIED = 32 
};
```

To Convert Each to a specific Brush I have the following code, Tested and it works

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(Enums.ClientStatus), typeof(Brush))]
public class StateValueColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Brush Brush = Brushes.Red;
        if (value is Enums.ClientStatus)
        {
            Enums.ClientStatus sv = (Enums.ClientStatus)value;

            switch (sv)
            {
                case Enums.ClientStatus.IMPORTAND:
                    Brush = Brushes.Blue;
                    break;
                case Enums.ClientStatus.MONITORED:
                    Brush = Brushes.Purple;
                    break;
                case Enums.ClientStatus.NEWCLIENT:
                    Brush = Brushes.Orange;
                    break;
                case Enums.ClientStatus.SATISFIED:
                    Brush = Brushes.Green;
                    break;
                case Enums.ClientStatus.DETERIORATING:
                    Brush = Brushes.Yellow;
                    break;
                case Enums.ClientStatus.DISATISFIED:
                    Brush = Brushes.Red;
                    break;
            }
        }
        return Brush;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

to do the Binding I did the following, which is not what our lecturer exactly wanted

```
<GridViewColumn Header="Status" Width="110">
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                 <TextBox Width="50" Background="{Binding Path=Status, Converter={StaticResource ColorConverter}}"></TextBox>
                 <TextBox Width="50" Background="{Binding Path=SatisFactory, Converter={StaticResource ColorConverter}}"></TextBox>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

We need to display each of the enums as a different color however a client can have multiple statuses i.e

```
var status = ClientStatus.NEWCLIENT | ClientStatus.SATISFIED;
```

This will now return a int value of 33

My Problem now is I used two properties in my Client to show seperate statuses which is incorrect we need to use Bitwise Operations ie.

```
if ((status & ClientStatus.NEWCLIENT) == ClientStatus.NEWCLIENT)
{
    //do whatever
}
```

so I can do the above code but how would I do the binding on one property to show multiple color's in the one gridviewcollumn, I search the forum but I missed it if this question or something similar was there

I am not really sure how to state the question so I will try it in other words

I want to display all selected enums in the column.

Thanks for any help or suggestions
Hope I made sence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you'd like to display an icon, image, or UI element for each value in the enumeration and have them be visible if the object's status matches that value.

I think I would create a simple StackPanel containing all the UI elements likes so:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
  <Rectangle Fill="Blue" 
             Visibility="{Binding Status, 
                                  Converter={StaticResource StatusToVisibilityConverter},
                                  ConverterParameter=NEWCLIENT}" />
  <Rectangle Fill="Green" 
             Visibility="{Binding Status, 
                                  Converter={StaticResource StatusToVisibilityConverter},
                                  ConverterParameter=SATISFIED}" />
  ...
</StackPanel>
```

Then in your StatusToVisibilityConverter compare the value of Status with the value in ConverterParameter (you can convert that to you enumeration's value with [TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783499.aspx) static method.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you I understand this method, im going to try this one out and will bring out a result :D

Answer (score 0):

Define DataTemplate name StatusDataTemplate, or a default DataTemplate for Enums.ClientStatus as TargetType.
In this template, define a 3 columns X 2 rows Grid.
In each grid cell, define a Border, having as background the binding using one of the 6 enum as ConverterParameter, with a converter that returns the 'right' color if value AND parameter = parameter, transparent otherwise.

Then you can use :

```
<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Status}" />
```

... if you used a default DTpl

Or :

```
<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Status}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource StatusTemplate}"/>
```